# compoundjs cannot require file in application controller

Tags: node.js, compoundjs

We're using CompoundJS to develop an application whose folder structure as follows:
compound

```
compoundApp
|-- app
|   |-- controllers
|   |   |-- application_controller.js
|   |   |-- login_controller.js
|   |-- utils
|   |   |-- email-utils.js
```

In the **application_controller.js**, we require the email-util.js as the following code:

```
var _ = require('underscore'),
passport = require('passport'),
    EmailUtils = require('./app/utils/email-utils.js')(compound);
```

We get this error when we start the application:

```
Error: Cannot find module './app/utils/email-utils.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Promise.eval (eval at <anonymous> (d:\TiniPlanet_SVN\src\TiniGame\trunk\tiNiWeb\node_module\compound\node_modules\kontroller\lib\base.js:157:17), <anonymous>:145:22)
```

We got the same issue with different folder levels:

```
EmailUtils = require('../app/utils/email-utils.js')(compound);
```

or

```
EmailUtils = require('../utils/email-utils.js')(compound);
```

or

```
EmailUtils = require('./utils/email-utils.js')(compound);
```

Could anyone help explain the issue and how to solve it. And how do we find the folder is being checked for require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require('../utils/email-utils.js')` should normally work, because that's the correct location.

However, apparently CompoundJS does something funky, since it's running your code using `eval`, which makes the require relative to some path from within the CompoundJS module itself (reading the CompoundJS docs, it's because you're using [`eval controllers`](http://compoundjs.com/man/controller.3.html#FILES)).

I think it's best resolved by adjusting the [`NODE_PATH`](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders) environment variable so it includes your base directory (`compoundApp`). That way, `require('app/utils/email-utils')` should work (although I'm not familiar with the intricacies of Node environment variables on Windows).

Comment: In case we don't use the NODE_PATH, to define the correct path, is there any possibility to know what the folder level it's at?

Comment: @TrangTungNguyen perhaps via `process.cwd()`, which returns the current working directory (which is usually the directory from where you started your app).